# use $addToSet to add an item inside an inner-array, to a specific field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

So, I have this collection. I am trying to add responseId of value 9 to the array of responsesIds, where the requestId is 2.

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    partsIds: [
      {
        requestId: 1,
        responesIds: [1, 2, 3, 4]
      },
      {
        requestId: 2,
        responesIds: [5, 6, 7, 8]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So the pseudocode here would be: `$addToSet:{responseIds:9} where requestId:2`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out a solution that works, I haven't given it an extensive test yet, if you find a better solution, I'd be more than happy to listen.

```
db.collection.update(
    { _id: 1, 'partsIds.requestId': 2 },
    { $addToSet: { 'partsIds.$.responsesIds': 9 } }
);
```

The `$` is called [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/), which gets the index of the first matching item in the query, (in my case that's index of 1) and you can use it in updating like so.